# Firebase dynamic link not taking me to the play store

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have generated a dynamic link through firebase dynamic link REST API and provided the android package name and ios bundle id but when i click on dynamic link if the app exists its work fine if not then instead of taking me to the play store it open the fallback link

if the app not exists in mobile then it should take me to the play store

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define mobile applications in firebase.
Then go to firebase -> Engage -> Dynamic Links
Continue by entering your domain information.
New Dynamic Links on click
You can continue by filling in the required information.

Comment: I have just added the android fallback link and iOS fallback link while generating the dynamic link. once I removed them the issue is resolved. Thanks